# How to add a extra field to Solr while importing CSV file?

Tags: shell, solr

I'm Importing data in solr from the shell script

```
./bin/post -c <core name> $DOWNLOADFILE
```

There are some fields in CSV file like `Name, Email, Phone,Added_on,Updated_on`

Now I want to add another field `is_deleted` = 0 into solr in every record after successful import.

so how to do that?

Comment: A default value that will be added automatically to any document that does not have a value in this field when it is indexed. If this property is not specified, there is no default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schema you can add this,

```
  <field name="is_deleted" type="pint" default="0" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

If the field is empty the default value will be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

Add a field in `schema.xml` like below.

```
<field name="is_deleted" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" default="0" />
```

If the data is not provided while indexing, then solr will use the default value specified in the `schema.xml` file. If default is not defined, solr ignores this field. If field is marked as required in `schema.xml` - solr will reject this document with error.